# How to check if a Flash message exists in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp

In Yii (both version) for flash messages we have methods like: `hasFlash` for checking if a flash message exists beforehand and `getFlash` to get the content of a specific flash message...

In Yii 1x I would say something like this (whether in the Controller or in a View):

View:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <?=Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Controller:

```
if($something->happend()) {
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'You\'ve done something wonderful.');
    return $this->redirect('/elsewhere');
}
```

In CakePHP 3 this seems impossible, since the only thing I can do is to set a Flash message:

```
$this->Flash->set('Welcome, to the real world.', [
    'element' => 'success',
]);
```

There are no `get` or `has` methods for Flash messages, or anything similar that I could find related to [FlashComponent](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html) and [FlashHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/flash.html) classes.

The other thing about this Flash messages implementation in CakePHP 3 is the way you render and show them to the visitor; you just say the following in your views/layout:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render(); ?>
```

That method will actually do the rendering, checking if a flash exists, whatever... and the thing is I need to check if a Flash message is sent/exists, then to do something else within the layout. Now it seems impossible to me or I am not looking in the right direction.

I would note that this is a very strange and bad implementation of Flash messages in CakePHP 3...

Finally, the question:

How can I check if a Flash message exists, whether in a view or in a controller?

Comment: Why is it "strange" (Just because you're used to Yii?) and why is it bad? It's pretty simple and works just fine. I find it very inconvenient to manually check for the flash just to render it. I don't mind improving the code, but just calling it bad because it doesn't meet *your* expectation doesn't make it bad. IMO checking if a flash message exists in a controller is *bad* design. This sounds like there is more logic in there that shouldn't be there. You're putting view layer related logic in in a controller. Pretty clearly a violation of the MVC pattern.

Comment: @burzum If you had any idea about flash messaging system, you'd realize that "render" method inside the FlashHelper actually has to perform a check and then render it forcefully without any control of if by the programmer. I call it a very bad design and an approach which is totally wierd. THanks.

Comment: A missing method you want makes it a bad design? Haha, please stick to Yii. ;) I was about to do a PR and add the missing method but for *some* reason I suddenly lost my motivation to do so.

Comment: Some day you'll still have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `key` while setting the Flash. see below

```
$this->Flash->set('Welcome, to the real world.', ['key' => 'alert']);
```

check by `key` in render before call

```
<?php 
if($this->Flash->render('alert')){
    echo $this->Flash->render('alert');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on [Setting Flash Messages](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html#setting-flash-messages) says that the messages are stored in the session. More specifically it says:

> FlashComponent’s __call() and set() methods optionally take a second parameter, an array of options:
>
> - key Defaults to ‘flash’. The array key found under the Flash key in the session.

So to check if a flash message exists you would do:

```
$session->check('Flash.flash')
```

Or if you specified a key when setting the flash message you would do:

```
$session->check('Flash.INSERT_CUSTOM_KEY')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have actually looked into FlashHelper class myself and found the same, but the bad thing that this is totally missed by the framework dev guys. This is a handy option to have.

Comment: Probably because nobody else had a need to do so before. ;) Feel free to create a ticket on Github and maybe someone will take care of even better: Do a pull request. I'll merge it if you include proper tests for the new method.

Answer (score 2):

One ugly and quick way to do this is:

```
<?php $flashRender = $this->Flash->render(); ?>
<?php if(!empty($flashRender)) : ?>
      <?= $flashRender ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Only render the flash when it is set

Answer (score -1):

$this->Session->check('Message.location_key');

**It returns true/false depending on whether there are any such flash messages set. ->read() does the same thing, but returns the flash data if there is (any and crucially, it leaves the session var so it can still be echoed later).**

Answer (score -1):

In Cakephp 4 you can easily do it using the following:

```
<?php if(!empty($this->getRequest()->getFlash())) : ?>
  <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: For me it worked with a slighly different variant:



`<?php if (!empty($this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Flash'))) : ?>`

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked with a slighly different variant in Cakephp 4:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Flash'))) : ?>
  <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?php endif;?>
```